# using .load to load pages from a navbar

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm using bootstrap's modal and I would like to have a navbar at the top of the modal that uses jquery's .load to change the view of the modal when clicked. I am able to get the modal up with the default view to show but I can't get the rest of the buttons to fire when clicked. Below id a simplified version of what I want. Thanks for any help.

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>X</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Account Settings</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button id="account" class="btn">Account</button>
        <button id="edit-account-users" class="btn">Users</button>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>Close</button>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
    accountData.init();
});

var accountData = {
    'init' : function() {
        $('.account-settings, #account-settings #account').click(function() {
            $('#account-settings').load('/partials/account/index.html', function() {
            $('#account-settings .wrapper').load('/partials/account/account_data.html');
        });
    });

    $('#edit-account-users').click(function() {
        $('#account-info .wrapper').load('/partials/account/account_users.html');
    });
}

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your buttons didn't fire is because your event bindings may be attached to elements that no longer exist.

Say if you were to replace content using `.load()`, the original event handlers to the elements will be lost. That's why event delegation is very useful here, bind the event to the document instead of the individual element. (You're not going to replace `document`) So when the user clicks anything inside the page, the event will be picked up by `document` and *delegated* to a child element according to the *selector* provided, eg. `#edit-account-users`.

Use event delegation `.on()` instead of `.click()`.

```
$(document).on('click', '#edit-account-users', function() {
        $('#account-info .wrapper').load('/partials/account/account_users.html');
});
```

Read more about `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/